# Adding zoom to Google Glass

Tags: android, android-camera, google-glass, google-gdk, libstreaming

I have an app that sends video via RTSP to a media server which can then be accessed. My question is how could I zoom the video feed in (even if I can just add a fixed zoom value to the code). I am using the libstreaming library so I am a bit unsure how to add the zoom function when using this.

I configure the camera resolution etc. in my `initRtspClient` function:

```
  private void initRtspClient() {
    // Configures the SessionBuilder
    mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
        .setContext(getApplicationContext())
        .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
        .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
        .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(640, 480, 20, 500000))
        .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView).setPreviewOrientation(0)
        .setCallback(this).build();
        ...
}
```

Would I just add the code to set the zoom level of the camera when I am setting these other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go with the following tutorial SmartCamera .this will gives you an features for zoom.

https://github.com/xjefftang/smartcamera

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is a quite a bit more complex that I need, I'm just looking the camera to be set to maximum zoom as soon as the app is launched.

Comment: @colin:Try with this one..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946271/camera-zoom-not-working..this is for max zoom for camera.